# How do I use javascript to insert text into a text element inside svg element in html?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am a javascript newbie and have been using document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML to insert text into

elements.
Now I have an svg image inside  which contains a  element into which I want to insert text. The following shows what I have tried, but which does not work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
       // some script stuff
        document.getElementById("textID").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
       // more script stuff
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        // some stuff
        <svg>
            // svg stuff        
            <text ID = "textID"></text>       
            // more svg stuff
       </svg>
    </body
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how I can use Javascript to get text into the text element?

I included what I tried in the body of the question. I was expecting the getElementById text to appear in the appropriate place in the svg image.